# Android SQLLiteDataBase cursor returning 0 rows

Tags: java, android, sql, database, android-cursor

For the life of me, I can't get the cursor to return any data. I've verified that their is data in the database and my insertions are working. The official error is:

> CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, **with a size of 0**

Top level declarations:

```
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    this.db = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

My function:

```
public String getRandomEntry()
    {
    int rand;
    Random random = new Random();
    int numEntries = (int)this.getCount();

    if(numEntries == 0)
        return "ERROR: Database is empty.";
    rand = random.nextInt(numEntries);

    Cursor cursor = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE 
            + " WHERE " + COLUMN_A + " = " + 0, null);

    Log.i("numEntries", Integer.toString(numEntries));
    Log.i("rand", Integer.toString(rand));
    Log.i("cursor", Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(0);
}
```

I've also tried grabbing the cursor as such:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE 
            + " WHERE " + COLUMN_A + " = " + 0, null);
```

Please give me your thoughts! Thank you!!

Comment: in the db... is COLUMN_A = 0? ... and what is the `rand` for?

Comment: STRING COLUMN_A = "_id";, sorry, should have included that.

Comment: I took out the random to isolate the problem to the Cursor. No matter if I look for COLUMN_A = 0,1,2.... (where COLUMN_A is the _id column in the database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing seems random here at all.  It appears that you are looking for column_a with a value of 0 every time.

I would assume that column_a has nothing with a value of 0.

Comment: I took out the random to isolate the problem to the Cursor. No matter if I look for COLUMN_A = 0,1,2.... (where COLUMN_A is the _id column in the database).

Comment: What does the Cursor look like if you don't add the 'where' clause?

Comment: Added two records. Without the 'where', the log properly reports cursor.getCount() = 2.

Comment: What are the ids?  Can you run a where with one of the id's from the Cursor?

Comment: Think I found the problem, I create my table as such:


    `private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
        + COLUMN_A + " " + TYPE_A + ", "
        + COLUMN_B + " " + TYPE_B + ", "
        + COLUMN_C + " " + TYPE_C + ", "
        + COLUMN_D + " " + TYPE_D + ");";`

Where: 
 `public static final String TYPE_A = "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT";`


The Autoincrement isn't gettings reset everytime I run (or even do a db.delete) so its adding records at 45,46,47,etc. right now...

How can I reset that Autoincrement?

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Comment: Yup that lead to a solution.

Thanks for your time NH

Answer (score 2):

First of all try to query this way:

```
String args[] = new String[]{"0"};

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_A + " = ?", args);
```

If this not helps check your db with external tool if you query return rows there.